# How do I install php-gd on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies

I need to install php-gd on CentOS 7.  I have very limited repositories on my network.  I cannot get a direct connection to the Internet with a Linux server.

I tried to install `php56w-gd-5.6.19.1.w7.x86_64.rpm`  But it needs php56w-common-5.6.19.1.w6.x86_64.rpm which depends on `libgmp.so.3` I get the error that this `.so.3` file is required. I cannot find this `so.3` file on the Linux server. So the error message is correct. `gmp.x86_64` is installed. Yum list gmp shows it.

I tried installing these packages:`gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.i686.rpm` and `gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64.rpm.` I tried a different way of installing php-gd.  I used `rh-php56-php-gd-5.6.5-7.el7.x86_64`.  But I got a message about it not updating the installed package.

I tried `yum clean all`. But when I repeated my installation attempts of the .rpm packages, I got the same problems.  I then tried two more gmp packages: `gmp-4.1.4-10.el5.x86_64.rpm` and `gmp.4.1.4-12.3_2.el5.x86_64.rpm` Neither would install. From `gmplib.org` I downloaded a .tar.gz file to install `gmp 6.1` It installed fine. But it failed to produce a `libgmp.so.3` file.

`yum list gmp` shows that gmp 6.0 is installed.  What package will satisfy my need for a `libgmp.so.3` requirement?  Is there a different way to install `php56w-common-5.6.19-1.w6.x86_64.rpm` or `php56w-gd-5.6.19.1.w7.x86_64.rpm`?  I need to get `php-gd` installed with version 5.6 (not any lower).

Update: rh-php56-php-gmp.x86_64 was successfully installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing rh-php56-php-gmp.x86_64 as well?

Comment: Probably the best solution would be to set up a mirror on your network so that yum can fetch & install remote packages.

Comment: Yes, I tried the rh-php56-php-gmp.x86_64.  Procedurally I cannot set up a mirror on my network.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum provides */libgmp.so.3
```

will list all packages which have this file.